# load pages using "load more" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a script which uses pagelinks number to show next and previous pages like:

prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 next

And the url changes to be www.domain.com/?page=2 . I'd like to change it to a (load more) button that appends the new data. I got this javascript so far:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


var new_btn = $('<div id="gig-more" class="gig-load-more" style="display: block;">   <button id="btn-white"  type="button" class="btn-standard-lrg btn-white"">Load More</button></div>');
  new_btn.insertAfter('#frame{$currentpage+1}');

  $('#btn-white').click(function() {


$.get('?page={$thenextpage}  ', function(html){ 
  $(html).find("#testframe").appendTo("div#testframe");
});
});
});
 </script>
```

{$currentpage} and {$thenextpage} are smarty variables used

Clicking the button in page (1) it loads the page(2) correctly. However, if the button is clicked again, it loads again and again the second page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are complicating it too much. You don't really need smarty for this. This is the whole thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Store what page to load next
nextpage = 2;

$('#load_more').click(function(event) {
  // Retains compatibility for those with no javascript
  event.preventDefault();

  // Fetch the data
  $.get('/ajax.php?page=' + nextpage, function(html){

    // Put the data where it belongs. I like it more this way
    $("div#testframe").append(html);

    // Keep the counter up-to-date
    nextpage++;
    });

  });
</script>
```

However you need a couple more of changes. You need to put in your html this button:

```
<a href = "?page=2" id = "load_more">Load more</a>
```

Note that this makes it backward compatible for those without javascript, like web crawlers, while it enhances the experience to meet your requirements for those who have it.

And create an **ajax.php** that is similar to the current index.php, but it only loads the data needed, since you don't want to make the user to have to load a bunch of things that will never be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francisco
your answer really helped me to get what i want
i just changed a little to suit my script
Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssss :)